# Script that allows you to take a list and create a tab for each item in the list

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a table with columns: PID, Project name, ... (14 Columns) like this

```
PID Project_name Department Plan Effort estimation ....

111 Project1         qw          50     60

111 Project1         sw          40     50

222 Project2         sw          40     50
......
```

I want to automatically create a tab for each PID, so that I have a tab named 111 with all data with PID 111 from sheet1, tab 222 with all data with PID 222... when I import the table from Excel into Google spreadsheets. Could someone help me?

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad for this site. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Something like here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/need-to-pull-rows-from-one-tab-to-another-tab-in-same-spreadsheet-that-meet-cert 
but here will be no tabs created automatically.

I think it must be like this (pseudo code): 
create tabs =UNIQUE(MasterSheet!A2:A) copy data =FILTER(MasterSheet!A2:Q60000, MasterSheet!A2:A60000 = "UNIQUE PID")

Comment: I found an google sheet add-on Tabify, which does exactly what I'm looking for, but it unfortunately hangs after some time (my table has ~60000 rows).

Comment: An add-on works well, it hangs because of the limit of 5000000 cells.

Comment: Are you saying that you need 60000 tabs?

Comment: No, there are ~ 200 unique PIDs. 
The problem is solved, google sheet add-on Tabify does what I needed.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is solved. Google sheet add-on Tabify does that. This add-on allows you to filter sheet results into new tabs.

"Tabify allows you to organize your spreadsheet data or Form Responses by creating a tab for each unique value found in a column. It will add tabs (sheets) to the spreadsheet based on the column you choose."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN51XbsDbRY

Comment: Please elaborate. Describe how the add-on helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: What should I elaborate? This add-on does exactly what I wrote above in my issue.
When you run Tabify and choose a column, a new tab (sheet) wil be created for each different value in that column.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN51XbsDbRY

Comment: Please checkout [Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4059/88163)